# How to copy my files from "On my ipad" to my Mac?

Tags: macos, ipad, data-synchronization

In the finder, when I connect my iPad PRO 2020 (up to date) to my iMac (10.15.6) *I can see* the folders and files of differents apps, ***but not the "On my ipad" folder.***

Is there a (simple) way to see it (and access it) in the finder or in the terminal ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is another simple possibility without using iCloud or Documents (by Readdle) directly via the app **Files** on iPad.

Choose **Connect to Server** from the top sidebar in **Files** and use the entry name how computers on your local network can access your computer from **Systems Preferences** > **Sharing**. Of course, the **File Sharing** service should be active.

As soon you are connected you will find your mac under **Shared** in **Files** sidebar.

Now you can copy/move files (also the one in **On My iPad**) in both directions.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't see the "On my iPad" folder, however, the easiest way I found was using iCloud or use the app [Documents by Readdle](https://apps.apple.com/fr/app/documents-par-readdle/id364901807)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I've found is to save or copy the iPad file to your iCloud drive if you have one or to Dropbox which you can get for both Mac and iPad.

There are ways to sync your iPad to your iMac but I have Hign Sierra and I can't use the method. The method is given [here](https://support.apple.com/guide/ipad/transfer-files-between-ipad-and-your-computer-ipad32dd03cd/ipados).

Comment: I use the given method (USB) and can't see the "On my ipad" folder.

Comment: it should appear in the Finder sidebar window..

Comment: I can see my Ipad on the finder. But in the "file" tab, I can see a folder for my apps but not the "On My Ipad" folder