# Make a folder on an iPad not visible on macOS

Tags: macos, ios, files.app

I have created a "Photos" folder on the "On My iPad" in Files.app on the iPad.

If I then connect to the iPad and look under Files on my Mac, I can't see this folder.

Is there a way to manipulate files on an iPad directly?

Comment: It seems this is simply not possible natively - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/400901/how-to-copy-my-files-from-on-my-ipad-to-my-mac

Comment: Unbelievable how parts of this just don't work.